# redirected automatically when the page is refreshed few times

Tags: javascript, php

I am building a program that has a countdown timer. the scenario is, when the countdown time reach 0 (it starts from 5 seconds) the page will be automatically refreshed.
the Question is, how to make the program directing to another page when the page is refreshed for three times?

Will it be using PHP or JavaScript or possible for both of them. Should I use a variable as a counter of the reloading page?

Comment: use localstorage and save page refresh count in that storage. on each page refresh check the count and when it become 3 redirect to another page

Comment: You can use PHP sessions to storage times. Write some code to let us to help you.

Comment: I will suggest that you explain your case in more details. Why should the initial page refresh 3 times? Is it important that the user can not cheat the system? Should the second page have "knowledge" about the 3 times refresh in the initial page?

Comment: @AlivetoDie Thanks for the suggestion, I'm working on it right now

Comment: @GiacomoMasseroniChiaro thank you, I will also try to use the session

Comment: @chrwahl yes true, I am building a kind of psychological test program, so in order to prevent the user on analyzing "what is going on" in the page, I create a countdown timer each pages so the user should choose the option provided within 5 seconds. Thus, when they did not choose any option when the initial page is refreshed for 3 times, their account ID's will be blocked.about the second page, yes, it needs to have a knowledge on how much the the previous page been refreshed. I am going to make a new scheme, when the 'total' page refreshed equals to 5 times, it will also block their ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sends to other page after 3 reloads.

```
var times = 0;
var item = localStorage.getItem("times");
if(Number(item) !== 0)
    times = Number(item);
setTimeout(function() {
    if(times < 4)
        location.reload();
    else if(times >= 4) {
        times = 0;
        localStorage.setItem("times", times);
        location.href = "https://www.google.com";
    }
    times++;
    localStorage.setItem("times", times);
}, 5000);
```

Comment: thank you, it works perfectly.
but in the line if(times < 4) should be times<3 so there only refresh the page 3 times in maximum. Also I deleted the second if condition (after else). Once again, thank you for helping